# Holding space and jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, 2d

I'm trying to make my first game and I want to create a timer between each jump. For example, if I hold down the spacebar for 0.5 seconds and after release I can jump minimum height. If I hold for 3.5 seconds, then I can jump medium height, so on. I can't figure out how to solve this. Overall, when the player release the spacebar then jump and not then when pressed.

My code looks like this:

```
IEnumerator Jump()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && (holdTime >= 0f))
        {
            jumpForce = 2f;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && (holdTime >= 3f))
        {
            jumpForce = 5f;           
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && (holdTime == 5f))
        {
            jumpForce = 10f;
        }
        else
        {
            //force player to jump
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving it all to the update loop.

```
 float holdTimer = 0f;
protected void Update()
{
    //Check if you released first
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        //Jump based on the time held
        if (holdTimer >= 5f)
        {
            jumpForce = 10f;
        }
        else if (holdTimer >= 3f)
        {
            jumpForce = 5f;
        }
        else
        {
            jumpForce = 2f;
        }
        //reset the timer
        holdTimer = 0f;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        //Increment the timer every frame.
        holdTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    }

}
```